# Plottin lavaan SEM/CFA in APA-style

Tags: r, data-visualization, structural-equation-modeling

I like doing SEM's with lavaan. But I dont like reporting them because I haven't found a good way to plot them in APA-style. I usually rebuild the model in PowerPoint and add the parameters by hand. What a pain!

To look at the results of the SEM I usually use semPaths from the semPlot package, which is great, but it's output is not in APA-style (or anything close).

How do you deal with that issue when presenting an SEM? Has anyone found a good solution for this?

Comment: Is there an APA style for path diagrams? I've never found anything that will automatically do a decent path diagram - I always do them in powerpoint.

Comment: To my knowledge (and surprise) there is no APA style for path diagrams but I assume the usual figure guidelines apply (black and white, etc.). Too bad that there is no decent solution out there. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Here's a powerpoint file of path diagrams that I use: I tend to find the most similar one and modify it. (I have a newer version, drop me an email [my email address is easy to find with Google] and I'll send it to you. www.jeremymiles.co.uk/misc/pathdiagrams.PPT

Comment: What a great collection. Thanks. I wrote you an email too.